# Toggle button doesn't work only for center element! (HTML / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

So I have three entries, all populated the same way. The top works. The bottom works. And the middle doesn't.  If only 1 worked or none worked, I might have some idea, but with just the middle failing, I'm scratching my head.  Same behavior in Edge and Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Lesson Prompts</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lesson Prompts</h1>
  <div id="prompts"></div>
  <script id="lessondata" type="application/json">
    {
      "prompts": [{
          "audio": "prompt1.mp3",
          "spanish": "Hola, ¿cómo estás?",
          "english": "Hello, how are you?"
        },
        {
          "audio": "prompt3.mp3",
          "spanish": "¿Qué hora es?",
          "english": "What time is it?"
        },
        {
          "audio": "prompt2.mp3",
          "spanish": "Me llamo Juan.",
          "english": "My name is Juan."
        }
      ]
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('lessondata').textContent);
    const promptsEl = document.getElementById('prompts');
    data.prompts.forEach(prompt => {
      const promptEl = document.createElement('div');
      promptEl.classList.add('prompt');
      promptEl.innerHTML = `
        <button class="toggle-btn">Show/Hide</button>
        <audio src="${prompt.audio}" controls></audio>
        <p class="spanish">${prompt.spanish}</p>
        <div class="english hidden">${prompt.english}</div>
      `;
      promptsEl.appendChild(promptEl);

      const toggleBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-btn');
      toggleBtns.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const promptEl = btn.parentElement;
          const englishEl = promptEl.querySelector('.english');
          englishEl.classList.toggle('hidden');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your HTML ?

Comment: What do you mean? It's right in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `addEventListener` out of the first `forEach`, otherwise your example #1,#2,#3 will be add event listeners for 1,2,3 times.

BTW, why the 1st and 3rd works in your code:
Because their events has been executed an odd number of times, while the 2nd sample is toggled twice every time you click it. (One plus one minus offset does nothing)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Lesson Prompts</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lesson Prompts</h1>
    <div id="prompts"></div>
    <script id="lessondata" type="application/json">
      {
        "prompts": [
          {
            "audio": "prompt1.mp3",
            "spanish": "Hola, ¿cómo estás?",
            "english": "Hello, how are you?"
          },
          {
            "audio": "prompt3.mp3",
            "spanish": "¿Qué hora es?",
            "english": "What time is it?"
          },
          {
            "audio": "prompt2.mp3",
            "spanish": "Me llamo Juan.",
            "english": "My name is Juan."
          }
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('lessondata').textContent);
      const promptsEl = document.getElementById('prompts');
      data.prompts.forEach((prompt) => {
        const promptEl = document.createElement('div');
        promptEl.classList.add('prompt');
        promptEl.innerHTML = `
              <button class="toggle-btn">Show/Hide</button>
              <audio src="${prompt.audio}" controls></audio>
              <p class="spanish">${prompt.spanish}</p>
              <div class="english hidden">${prompt.english}</div>
            `;
        promptsEl.appendChild(promptEl);
      });

      const toggleBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-btn');
      console.log(toggleBtns.length);
      toggleBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
          const promptEl = btn.parentElement;
          const englishEl = promptEl.querySelector('.english');
          console.log(englishEl);
          englishEl.classList.toggle('hidden');
        });
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked, more importantly I now understand what was happening and I never in a million years would have considered it was failing because it was an even numbered item.  Thank you!   Now I just need to make it a lot prettier, hehe